# Does a well-pointed topos with enough projectives satisfy the internal axiom of chioice?

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory, topos-theory, axiom-of-choice

If yes, then I am also wondering if being well-pointed can be weakened to boolean (i.e. this is in the context of using Set as our metalogic so that well pointed Topoi are boolean). If not, then any good explicit counterexample would be very instructive to have.

In particular, do presheaf toposes over groupoids (which are boolean with enough projectives) satisfy the IAC?

Comment: If you have well-pointedness, the internal AC and the external one should agree, no? And I don't think it's sufficient, since the axiom PAx (which is essentially "enough projectives" in a weak form of ZF) is nontrivial and does *not* imply AC.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense for a general topos. What if we restrict the Topos to be a Grothendieck topos specifically?

Comment: A well pointed Grothendieck topos is suddenly Set. No?

Comment: @David: Didn't Blass prove that EPSet + SVC imply AC over ZF?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'd have to check, but I think youre right. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/presentation+axiom says that DC and CC follow from the one-element set behaving as it should plus the axiom in question, and, oh, here it is:  https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/small+violations+of+choice#svc_and_coshep

Comment: @David: I was about to make that same comment when the question was first posted, but after taking a look at Blass' famous 1979 paper, I decided to let people who know what all those words mean take centre stage.

Comment: A Grothendieck topos satisfies IAC if and only if it is a Boolean étendue (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/axiom+of+choice#internal_form). Because presheaf toposes over groupoids are Boolean étendues, they will satisfy IAC.

Comment: Ah, this was very helpful. The concept of being an etendue is exactly what I was looking for. It's also very interesting to see that presheaf toposes are boolean if and only if they satisfy IAC (and if and only if the underlying category is a groupoid).